# regex for repeating words in a string to repalce one in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How can I replace repeating words in a string, with just one copy?

For example:

```
hi hi hello hello hello bye bye bye bye
```

should become:

```
hi hello bye
```

My code :

```
import re
s = "hi hi hello hello hello bye bye bye bye"
m=re.sub(r'(?<!\S)((\S+)(?:\s+\2))(?:\s+\2)+(?!\S)', r'\2', s)
print m
```

output:

```
hi hi hello bye
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
re.sub(r'\b(\S+)(?: \1)+\b', r'\1', s)
```

The `\b` escape is a zero-width match for a word break (either whitespace or the start or end of the text). Using it lets the rest of the pattern work without stuff like `goodbye bye` or `foo foobar` getting trimmed incorrectly.

The inner part of the pattern matches a word followed by one or more repeats of the same word separated by spaces. The whole thing is replaced by one copy of the word.

Comment: Thank you so much :) @Blckknght